# How to get files downloaded from url? (not to open in browser)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, download

I am new to java.I need to download pdf/txt/.xls or any file on click on download option.
In my case i am having certain values in array list and displaying in the jsp.
In my list(namelist) iam having

```
name=rahul
url=files/en/software/rahul.txt
name=roshan
url=files/en/software/roshan.pdf
```

when i iterate the (namelist) and display the above in jsp,i my jsp

```
<td valign="top">${namelist.name}</td>

<td colspan="2" valign="top">                           
<a href="${namelist.url}"/>
<img src="/images/download.gif" alt="Download" border="0" align="right"></a><br/><br/>
</td>
```

so in my jsp iam having lot of user names and corresponding files for them in url.
On click of download the file is opening in browser with url
http://www.xxx.com/files/en/software/roshan.pdf

But i want this to open as a pop up asks user for save as/open option.
When passed this url to controller i am getting only the value /files/en/software/roshan.pdf.
I have searched for the same every where they are suggesting to use
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+name);

so i have created a controller named download and on click of download i mapped the url like this

```
<a href='<c:url value="/download.sp?name=${namelist.name}&downloadUrl=${namelist.url}"/>'>
<img src="/images/download.gif" alt="Download" border="0" align="right"></a><br/><br/>
```

Here in my controller.
I donno exactly what to do, i have written like this

```
public ModelAndView download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        cat.debug(" download: begin");
        ModelAndView modelView = super.handleRequest(request, response);
        String url = request.getParameter("downloadUrl");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+name);
        String viewName = "swl_download";
        modelView.setViewName(viewName);
        return modelView;
}
```

The above is opening popup with the same name.I want to include more in controller so that on click of download the file should be the same file in url(what to include /change in the above controller).
Please help me in resolving this.Thanks i advance for helping me.

Comment: Are you getting the download filename as swl_download?

Comment: Have a look the link: [File-download-servlet](http://www.coderanch.com/t/366358/Servlets/java/File-download-servlet). You can do it with just servlet itself, you do not need to involve spring mvc.

Comment: @subirkumarsao: that code is for example im getting download file name as rahul.txt ,but how to get the file in the url related to rahul? please help me.

Comment: @elber : my requirement is to spring-mvc.

Comment: @Rahul So if you use Servlet someone will fire you? Actually you are using servlet(spring will not work without it for web)

Answer (score 1):

Need to see what the sql_download view is doing.

In general, I set the content disposition in the view itself. So my custom AbstractView implemenation would look something like :

`response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);`
`response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");`
`OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();`
`helperClass.exportDataToExcel(data, out);`

The content type is also important, to help your browser choose the correct application to load the document.

You should know that these headers are only a suggestion to a browser, Browsers are free to interpret them in their own way. So you will not be able to force all browsers to show a "Open or Save" dialog.

Hope this helps.